# Someone's been photobombing me - what gives?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

So Prompto takes pictures all day long. Usually it's your characters, some scenery, monsters you fought that day, etc.

Recently, someone who definitely wasn't there when the photo has been taken has been showing up. The game has even specifically pointed this out to me by having the characters mention it. I'm on chapter 9 and this seems to happen about once every few days... is there any significance to this?

Comment: Is it something to the tune of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uj_rHR4wwjU) or [this](http://www.polygon.com/2016/12/1/13805180/final-fantasy-15-carbuncle-photos)? Beware of potential spoilers (not sure if those links are really spoilers).

Comment: It's the first link. The fact that it continues to happen and there seems to have been effort put in (e.g., the character will be acting/reacting along with my characters) seems to suggest there is some significance.

Comment: Do you want spoilers?

Comment: If the answer requires spoilers, I think saying something like "Yes, it's significant because..." and then tagging the actual reason would be perfect

Answer (score 6):

Based on your comments, the "person" in the pictures is actually [Gentiana](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Gentiana), the Messenger of the Gods. She does it occasionally and someone points it out if you look at the picture on the reel.

There is no benefit to this aside from getting the [Immortal Photobomb](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/game/final-fantasy-xv/trophy/162079-Immortal-Photobomb.html) trophy/achievement. After that, it's just for fun. (Personally, I'm saving every picture she manages to get in)

There is no significance other than the fact that it's showing that she is with you, despite you not knowing it.

<sub>Note: her wikia article does include spoilers unrelated to this lower down on the page, so read at your own caution.</sub>

Comment: I've heard that she start to appear when you've called Umbra. Since you're in a sort of "dream" she'll make those appearance. While you're in the present she won't photoboom you since you're not "dreaming"

Comment: @Warface I'm not sure what you mean by that. I believe that I read Gentiana will start photobombing from the time you first meet her.

Comment: I've meant that she'll appear only if you've called Umbra and are in the past. Not sure she'll appear in the present. But I may be wrong, but seems more appropriate that she's appearing while you're in the past

Comment: Should have tag a spoiler there... ****Spoiler**** but no you're not

Comment: Is there any significance to it or is this just an easter egg of sorts? The specific commentary by the characters, as well as the interactivity of it, makes me wonder.

Comment: @twobugs it's just an Easter egg, really. There's no special meaning, from what I've seen.

Comment: @Warface I saw her in photos lots of times before I ever called Umbra.